# Change the action when clicking on a list item

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I would like to change the destination URL when clicking on a list item / item title so it will no send me to view the item but will send me to a different URL base on the item.
I am not looking to replace the Links list but to use the list title as URL query filter.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it using the custom Page / Customize the View Page in the SharePoint Designed. Please refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx) article on how you can achieve it using the SPGridView control

Comment: I have found this tutorial  
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/cizi/archive/2009/01/01/filtering-data-views-with-query-string.aspx
that is very helpful but I'm looking to make the change so when clicking the title no mater where you are (not in a specific page) it will refer me to the URL. smiler to what happen when you click on a catagory at a blog site.
Thank
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you'd like to do (maybe screenshot mock ups would help?), but here's some general advice.

If you want to change the behaviour of a control then investigate the properties of the control as kusek has suggested. If the properties don't do what you need then try overriding the control to change what is rendered.

If the above doesn't work out or you want to change how these links render no matter where they appear on the page, then you need to look at a page-level solution. The most common are jQuery that can dynamically replace the URLs with JavaScript, or an HTTP module which is much more low level and will actually alter the HTML rendered to the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Alex, I will try to explain myself better.
I'm want to implement a TAG option to a document library simpler to the Category list at a Blog site.
So far I have added a column to the doc lib that look up the items form a list I have created. so now i have the option to group and filter the doc lib by this column, I want that when a user press on an item on that column the doc lib will display only items with the same TAG.
I have created a URL query filter, but I don't know howto continue from there.
Thanks Amit

Comment: OK. This is certainly something you can dev or have you seen http://www.kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductID=517&ProductSubNodeID=518 or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc374980.aspx